# Why does ImageView fades inside CardView?

Tags: android

I am using a `TextView` and `ImageView` inside a `CardView`.

Now the problem is, even though both the image and text are black in color I am getting a faded gray color. What might be causing this? And what's the best fix for this?

Here is the code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_below="@id/TitleBar2"
    android:alpha="0.1"
    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"


    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/final_loc"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Its because of `android:alpha="0.1"` ? Setting alpha on parent view makes all it's children visible only for 1/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the Alpha.The lower the aplha, the less you will see. Here is a fix:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_below="@id/TitleBar2"
android:alpha="1"
android:id="@+id/card_view2"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"


android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/locIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/final_loc"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either remove android:alpha="0.1"
or change it to android:alpha="1"